# Use tab in a Java console-application to move around the screen

Tags: java, console-application

First and foremost, my java skills are minimal. I have been tasked with making a console application that will resemble an old CICS system still being used. So the need to allow the user to "tab" to areas of the screen to enter data is required. Then, based on inputs, the console will execute as expected.

I am not asking for anyone to write the code, I just need some help finding a tutorial (I'm an old C hack) to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know how to do this with console (I think it is not possible without a third party library), but may I ask why don't you consider using a GUI? Tab browsing works ok, and if the reason is consistency for old users, you can arrange it with the same pattern that the old screens.

Comment: It might be more genuine to have a console based application, but it would be significantly easier just to show a JFrame and show a similar input screen in the frame, and will be easier for users to boot.

Comment: The question isn't about whether he should use console, it's how to use console.  Management puts conditions like this on applications all the time for various reasons.

Comment: My inital thoughts was to use a GUI, and create an illusion for the consistency for the old users. However my management chain is more sales savy, not technical and my skill base is not Java. So the design was given to me as a console app, and now I am attempting to research this before I go back to work tomorrow.

Comment: you will have all kinds of fun, then. Nothing like killing yourself for something that turns out really bad, to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This interactivity is not available in pure Java on the text console. All input is line buffered in the text console.

You can do this with a GUI, which you can make look like a text console, but it would be easier to make it look like a regular windows program (as its the default behaviour)

EDIT: You do this

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    while(true)
        System.out.println(System.in.read());
}
```

and press tab many times you get just

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
10
```

only after you hit enter, even if you run this from an xterm.

Comment: +1 There are some IDEs that allow visual drawing of the windows. I don't like that, but this can speed up the process of making a GUI quick & dirty. You can make with the same layout of the old console program. However, Java is not made for console. If you need it, use C

Comment: Or you could use a curses library like http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/ - an old C guy might be familiar enough with curses that that is viable

Comment: @Erick, If that is so there must be examples on the web somewhere.  Can you point me to one?  Have you ever tried to do this?

Comment: You can use ANSI escape codes (crap or not), its the reading one character as it happens, you can't do.

Comment: @Erick, all you say is that you can do it, but you don't give an example.